# change the value of eworldui timepicker using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, components, client-side

I'm using [this asp.net control Time picker](http://www.eworldui.net/CustomControls/TimePickerDemo.aspx)

My question is, how can I change the value of time picker using javascript?

This is the code I've tried, but no luck(it did not work)

```
document.getElementById('<%= tpSchedIN.ClientID %>').text = '4:00 AM';
document.getElementById('<%= tpTimeIN.ClientID %>').value = '4:00 AM';
```

Comment: Yes that is a component. try visit this link
http://www.eworldui.net/CustomControls/TimePickerDemo.aspx